# How to make small shoes fit bigger feet

Tags: clothing, shoes

I received a pair of nice sneakers as a gift. I like them a lot, but they are about a size too small. I can squeeze into them, but it is very uncomfortable. **How can I expand the shoes, so that they will fit bigger feet and be more comfortable?** I would prefer a hack that doesn't damage the shoes. *Note: I don't need to just shape the shoes, I need to make them bigger.*

Answer (score 2):

The best hack for this is to use heat because heat makes things expand. All you will need is a hairdryer, a thick pair of socks (or two thinner pairs of socks), and your shoes. Put the socks on and then put the shoes on. Now, put the hairdryer on the highest heat. Blow dry the areas where the shoe needs to expand (usually the toe and maybe the sides). Bend and flex your feet while you are blow drying. You usually have to do this for 20-30 minutes per shoe. Make sure to hold the hairdryer at least 2 inches (5 cm) away from the shoe to avoid damage.

Comment: I think you should put this answer with the breaking in shows question. Just because you have an answer still does not make the question not a dupe, you are just expanding on how to make a new pair of shoe fit will, which is breaking in shoes. Think about it, then consider answering in the other question.